# Rockfall analysis (Nearest neighbor downhill) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, watershed, nearest-neighbor

I am working on a rockfall guide for QGIS and I'm currently stuck on one of the stages.

I currently at a point in the guide where I have two point layers one `"rockfall release point"`-layer and `"braking point"`-layer.

We are assuming that any rockfall will loosen from a release point, continue down the slope in the steepest direction, then begin to brake when it reaches a braking point, before stopping shortly thereafter.

[image: Rockfall release and braking points with drainage]

I was first planning on calculating drainage area for each braking point using watersheds like in ArcGIS Pro, where you can add a `"pour point field"`, and then find which drainage field each release point is placed in *(like in the figure above)*.

[image: ArcGIS Watershed]

The only similar thing I can find in QGIS is `r.water.outlet` where you have to type in one coordinate, do the calculation and start all over again - this is going to be hard considering I have 2.5m points.

A solution similar to the ArcGIS one would probably be the easiest. The other solution that I can come up with is doing a nearest neighbour analysis between the two layers, but then I also have to make sure that it only joins the point that is at the steepest slope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have a simple script that iterates over points and apply `r.water.outlet` to each one. You just need to add this code as a new script.

[image: image1]

It will ask for three things:

- Points layer.
- Flowdir layer (produced from dem file).
- Output file.

The resulting rasters will contain the id of the point at the end of the filename.

```py
##Rockfall=group
##RockfallAnalysis=name
##points=vector Point
##flowdir=raster
##outputfolder=folder

from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo, QSettings, QVariant
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
import os, glob, processing, string, time, shutil, os.path, subprocess

#crear capa vectorial a partir de la ruta anterior
layer = QgsVectorLayer(points, "shp", "ogr")
features = layer.getFeatures()

#raster extension for grass rwateroutlet
rasterlayer = QgsRasterLayer(flowdir,"rasterlayer")
rasterext = rasterlayer.extent()
xmin = rasterext.xMinimum()
xmax = rasterext.xMaximum()
ymin = rasterext.yMinimum()
ymax = rasterext.yMaximum()
extension = "%f,%f,%f,%f" %(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

#iterate over points
count=int(1)
for f in features:
    geom = f.geometry()
    #create coordinate of point
    a = geom.asPoint()
    point = str(str(int(a[0]))+','+str(int(a[1])))
    id = str(count)
    #name of the raster file
    outputfile = str(outputfolder+"/"+"rockfall"+"_"+id+".tif")
    print ("Processing id:"+' '+id)
    #process
    processing.runalg("grass7:r.water.outlet",
    flowdir,
    point,
    extension,
    0,
    outputfile)
    count+=1
```

Here some picks:

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

---

EDIT: SCRIPT FOR QGIS 3.8

Process resume: layer iteration --> r.water.outlet --> polygonize --> merge all

Here is the complete script ready to be add to your tools: https://github.com/cesarkero/QGIS_scripts/blob/master/QGIS_3.8/WaterOutletIterator.py

It have been hard as I tried to learn as the same time how to create an script for qgis 3.8 where different tools are used. I've set the keep temporal files by default because I needed to know how exactly the different steps where working, but, remember, if you want to execute it with your millions of points UNCHECK that boolean or you HDD/SDD will get out of the game.

Now it is open to you if you want to dissolve those polygons or join the attributes to the "losnepunkt" or "uphill"points...or whatever you are trying to do.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: PD: This has been developed in QGIS 2.18.25

Comment: Thanks a lot for the script :) Unfortunately this gets kinda messy when you have a few million points. In theory I could run this then merge all the .tiff files, but because of the bbox I'm working with each .tiff is about 200mb.

Comment: Could you share your layers to try something different ?

Comment: Here is the data:
https://bit.ly/2Zm6vVt

Flowdir.tif, losnepunkt = release point and bremsepunkt = brake point.

Comment: I've checked the data. I guess that your final goal is to have not a raster for each point but a polygon layer with all the "basins" for each one of the points, for example identifying each basing with the point id ? If this is the think I could add that to the script for you.

Comment: That would be amazing! Do you have any ideas about how we could get around the storage issue when processing this many points? :)

Comment: It's easy if you just need the final shp and not each one of the raster files. I hope I can try something in the afternoon.

Comment: Thanks a lot César :)

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at it? :)

Comment: I fighting with the script in QGIS 3.8 but is not as easy as I though, I need to keep trying. Is an R script suitable for you ? I think I could do it much easily than in the new python scripting.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply César. Too bad that it's hard in QGIS, I am not sure how well adding an R-part in the QGIS guide will work out, but I guess it's better than nothing ^.^

That said, I may have to continue trying to find a solution in QGIS - seeing that the decision is not entirely up to me. (one of the things we are trying to show with the guide is that people don't have to buy ESRI and can instead use QGIS :S)

Comment: PD: don't be afraid of the code. Just create a new python script, copy it, save that .py and execute it.

Comment: Thx a lot! I’ll check it out tomorrow morning  You have done an awesome job César 

Comment: It worked when I tested for 50ish points. Now I've started for a few million points, and it looks like it's going to take some hours. I'll get back to you with the results.

Comment: I'd like to know if this code could be easily converted to some parallel process but right know I have no idea. I will make some research about it. Hope it works for the moment ;-)

Comment: It works great for smaller areas/few points, but it would be nice to have a look at parallel processing (my computer calculated for about 3 days before it had a hiccup and terminated the processing >.<). I'll see if I'm able to edit the code to make it run faster ^^

Comment: One possible solution is to open as many qgis sessions as cores your pc have, split your data in the same parts and execute the tool for each dataset. Not the cleanest solution but you will speed the process a lot. It is cpu intense but I've tryed with an 8GB ram pc and it worked. I'd be glad if you could check mine as answer while there is no other better solution. Good luck ¡